# Adding the jomsocial toolbar to a module in joomla 3.0

Tags: php, joomla, toolbar, jomsocial

I need your help. Is it possible to add the jomsocial toolbar to a module in joomla 3.0 programmatically? In the past (Joomla 1.5 / 2.5) a few different methods worked but I guess upgrades changes this. I have searched high and low and tried every method I know. Thanks in advance!

**This is my code that used to work:**

// TOOLBAR
////////////////////////////////

```
require_once( JPATH_ROOT . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'core.php');
CFactory::load( 'libraries' , 'toolbar' );
$toolbar_lib = CToolbarLibrary::getInstance();
print $toolbar_lib->getHTML(_showMiniHeaderUser);
```

// (END) TOOLBAR
////////////////////////////////

**This code is the common way:**

```
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'core.php');
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'toolbar.php');
$toolbar    = CToolbarLibrary::getInstance()->getHTML();
echo '<div id="community-wrap">' . $toolbar . '</div>';
```

Neither of these methods work in jomsocial 3.0 or joomla 3.0 anymore and Jomsocial documentation doesn't offer any suggestions.

Comment: Something you would be best off asking the developer on JomSocial. I can't access this page as I haven't got JomSocial but login and have a look at the API: http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/Toolbar_API

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for the response, I've taken a look at the API link you sent, and it doesn't offer any documentation on implementing the toolbar just manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

your answer is herer:
i think it is also free and support js 3.0

http://www.knuddelesel.de/en/downloads/viewdownload/4/2.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>/**<br />
  Start Jomsocial Toolbar<br />
*/</p>
<p><br />
  if(JFile::exists(JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_community/libraries/core.php'))<br />
  {<br />
  require_once( JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_community/libraries/core.php' );<br />
  require_once( JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_community/libraries/toolbar.php' );<br />
  $appsLib    = CAppPlugins::getInstance();<br />
  $appsLib-&gt;loadApplications();<br />
  $appsLib-&gt;triggerEvent( 'onSystemStart' , array() );<br />
  if( class_exists( 'CToolbarLibrary' ) )<br />
  {<br />
  echo '&lt;div id=&quot;community-wrap&quot; style=&quot;min-height: 0 !important;  height: auto !important; margin: 0 !important;&quot;&gt;';<br />
  if( method_exists( 'CToolbarLibrary' , 'getInstance' ) )<br />
  {<br />
  $jsToolbar  = CToolbarLibrary::getInstance();<br />
  echo $jsToolbar-&gt;getHTML();<br />
  }<br />
  else<br />
  {<br />
  echo CToolbarLibrary::getHTML();<br />
  }<br />
  echo '&lt;/div&gt;';<br />
  }<br />
  }<br />
  /**<br />
  End Jomsocial Toolbar<br />
  */ </p>
```

Comment: Please also add some description about code that what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same for a while, very much frustrated there's no info in official docs, and eventually I came across this. It helped me a lot, thanks! Your solution actually works:

```
include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/core.php';

$toolbar = CToolbarLibrary::getInstance()->getHTML();
echo '<div id="community-wrap">' . $toolbar . '</div>';
```

Using joomla 3.3 and jomsocial 3.2

Comment: It renders an empty toolbar. Joomla 3.3.6, Jomsocial 3.2.1.4.

Comment: Solved! The page is loading `bootstrap.css` and it's hidding the menu items through `.gbs3 .collapse { display:none }`